# How do I sum two matrices or data frames that share only some elements in common using R?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, merge

I have two large data frames that I would like to perform element-wise operations on. In my case, I'd like to essentially do a matrix addition on two matrices that have partially-overlapping column and row names.

For example:

```
A <- matrix(rep(1,4),nrow=2)
colnames(A) <- c("a","b")
rownames(A) <- paste("r", seq(1,2,1), sep="")
B <- matrix(rep(10,4),nrow=2)
colnames(A) <- c("b","c")
rownames(B) <- paste("r", seq(2,3,1), sep="")

A
   a b
r1 1 1
r2 1 1

B
    b  c
r2 10 10
r3 10 10
```

I would like to sum A+B by column-and-row names to get:

```
>S
   a  b  c
r1 1  1  0
r2 1 11 10
r3 0 10 10
```

The row and column names in the matrices (or data frames) only partially overlap, so the final matrix will have different dimensions than the individual ones. In this toy example, the only overlapping cell is row:b/col:r2. I take empty cells to equal 0.

I can do it in a very clumsy way by subsetting matrices by overlapping rows and columns, then sorting and adding the submatrices, and finally by concatenating the non-overlapping bits. My real data are gene expression matrices with ~20,000 rows (genes) and ~10,000 columns (cells).

Comment: Your example is giving errors. Please correct. Also your example is different than what you have showed.

Comment: Your code is  `matrix(rep(1,9),nrow=3)`, but showed different

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed the code for the example.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `data.table` and this should be efficient.  Place the `matrix`es in a `list`, convert the `matrix` to `data.table`, create row names as a column ('rn'), rbind the data.tables (`rbindlist(...)`), grouped by 'rn' get the `sum` of other columns

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(list(A, B), function(x) setDT(as.data.frame(x), 
 keep.rownames = TRUE)), fill = TRUE)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = rn]
#   rn a  b  c
#1: r1 1  1  0
#2: r2 1 11 10
#3: r3 0 10 10
```

#### data

```
A <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
c("r1", "r2"), c("a", "b")))

B <- structure(c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
c("r2", "r3"), c("b", "c")))
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked great and was very fast, although I'm not sure why. From searching stack exchange I gathered that `[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = rn]` takes the subset of the columns of the data table not named ('rn'), and sums by rn. One-liners tend to confuse me.

Comment: @slackoverflow  YOu are right.  SD is subset of data.table.  Here, it would take the sum of all other columns grouped by 'rn'.